# PHP Validation Form with email sending an HTML template issue

Tags: php, forms, email, header

Im building a PHP form for a customer and i get some issue with the collecting datas into the Form has "Post" method, and the PHP section is complicated for me.

First, i want to use custom HTML template, which is displaying well, but it seems that the post collecting values are brooke. Also, the $headers datas seem to not be added (email is coming with no $from value, also no $to value).

I need help for this. Here is the html and php section. Please take a note, i'm not a JavaScript programmer, but i try to learn has my best knowlege and time goes. I've start from nothing.

Here is the Form HTML structure (reCaptcha is missing its normal):

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

          <script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            lang : 'fr',
        };
        </script>

            <style type="text/css">
            .field-error .control-label,
            .field-error .help-block,
            .field-error .form-control-feedback {
                color: #ff0039;
            }

            .field-success .control-label,
            .field-success .help-block,
            .field-success .form-control-feedback {
                color: #2780e3;
            }
        </style>

    <form method="post" action="envoi_appel_de_service.php">                
    <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#337ab7 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Informations sur l'adresse du service</p>

          <!-- Nom de la compagnie -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nom_compagnie" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Nom de la compagnie</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_compagnie" placeholder="Le nom de l'entreprise">
                </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Adresse -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="adresse" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Adresse</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adresse" placeholder="Adresse de l'entreprise">
                </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Ville -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="ville" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Ville</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ville" placeholder="Le nom de la ville de l'entreprise">
                </div>
          </div>

         <!-- Province -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="province" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;" id="province">Province</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option>Alberta</option>
                      <option>Colombie-Britanique</option>
                      <option>Ile-du-Prince-Edouard</option>
                      <option>Manitoba</option>
                      <option>Nouveau-Brunswick</option>
                      <option>Nouvelle-Ecosse</option>
                      <option>Nunavut</option>
                      <option>Ontario</option>
                      <option selected="selected">Quebec</option>
                      <option>Saskatchewan</option>
                      <option>Terre-Neuve-Labrador</option>
                      <option>Territoires du Nord-Ouest</option>
                      <option>Yukon</option>
                      </select>
                 </div>
          </div>

            <!-- Code postale -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="code_postale" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Code postale</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="code_postale" placeholder="XXX XXX">
                </div>
          </div>

           <!-- Nom de la personne ressource -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="nom_responsable" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Nom du responsable</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom_responsable" placeholder="Nom de la personne ressource sur place">
                </div>
          </div>

           <!-- Telephone -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Téléphone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="X XXX XXX-XXX ext XXXX">
                </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Adresse courriel -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="courriel" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Adresse courriel</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="courriel" placeholder="Adresse courriel valide">
                </div>
          </div>


        <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#A41313 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Informations sur le produit</p>

         <!-- Marque -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="marque" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Marque</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marque" placeholder="Marque du produit">
                </div>
          </div>

             <!-- Modèle -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="modele" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Numéro de modèle</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modele" placeholder="Veuillez inscrire le numéro de modèle">
                </div>
          </div>

            <!-- Garantie -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="garantie" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Garantie</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="garantie" placeholder="Est-ce que le produit est sous garantie?">
                </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Description du problème -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Description du problème</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="description"></textarea>
                </div>
          </div>

          <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#337ab7 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Préférences pour le rendez-vous</p>

          <!-- Disponibilité -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="disponibilite" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Disponibilité</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="disponibilite" placeholder="Quel est le meilleur moment pour vous joindre?">
                </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Coordonnées -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="coordonnees" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Coordonnées</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coordonnees" placeholder="Optionel">
                </div>
          </div>

            <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#A41313 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sécurité Anti-Spam</p>

          <!-- Validation reCaptcha franco Google -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="input12" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="padding-top:28px !important;">S&eacute;curit&eacute; anti-spam</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MASKING"></div>
                      </div>    
                </div>

          <!-- Soumettre -->
          <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="submit" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right">&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                     <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre</button>
                </div>
          </div>

          </form>
```

and here is the PHP section:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

 $to = "MASKING";
 $from = $_POST['courriel'];
 $subject = "Réception d'un appel de service";
 $nom_compagnie = $_POST['nom_compagnie']; // required
 $adresse = $_POST['adresse']; // required
 $ville = $_POST['ville'];
 $province = $_POST['province'];
 $code_postale = $_POST['code_postale'];
 $nom_responsable = $_POST['nom_responsable'];
 $courriel = $_POST['courriel'];
 $marque = $_POST['marque'];
 $numero_modele = $_POST['numero_modele'];
 $garantie = $_POST['garantie'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];              
 $disponibilite = $_POST['disponibilite']; // required
 $coordonnees = $_POST['coordonnees']; // required

 $headers = 'From: '.$courriel."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



 $message = "
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
<html>
<head>
<title>Appel de service (rempli sur le site internet)</title>
<style type=\"text/css\">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Cambria, \"Hoefler Text\", \"Liberation Serif\", Times, \"Times New Roman\", serif;
    color: #272727;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style=\"font-size: 1.25em; font-family: Gotham, ʼHelvetica Neueʼ, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\">Vous avez re&ccedil;u une demande dʼappel de service en ligne.</h2>
<table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Inations sur lʼadresse du service</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Nom de la compagnie</td>
      <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$nom_compagnie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Adresse</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$adresse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Ville</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$ville</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Province</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$province</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Code postale</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$code_postale</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Nom du responsable</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$nom_responsable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$telephone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Adresse courriel</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$courriel</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Informations sur le produit</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Marque</td>
      <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$marque</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Num&eacute;ro de mod&egrave;le</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$numero_modele</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Garantie</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$garantie</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">
      <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">Description du probl&egrave;me :</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height=\"75\" colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">$description</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Pr&eacute;f&eacute;rences pour le rendez-vous</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Disponibilit&eacute;</td>
      <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$disponibilite</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Coordonn&eacute;es</td>
      <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$coordonnees</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
 ";

 // Always set content-type when sending HTML email

 mail($to, $courriel, $message, $headers,
 "From: $from\n" . 
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"); 


 }
 ?>
```

Has you can see, all values are empty, headers too. Im stuck and had no idea why it doesn't work. If someone can help me with this please, thanks a lot.

[IMAGE: Email received from the php form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgixG.png)

Comment: any form field presented in your form is not having `name` attribute (they are having `id` which should be actually  `name`) except  submit button. so provide them `name` attribute and then your values will come.

Comment: So i just to rename id has a name="" and will be resolved? But the other point is the $to and $from, will be fixed too? I will try this right now.

Comment: 99% of it, yes. But your headers will fail. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php you're using 5 parameters. There is a 5th available, but isn't used for what you're doing.

Comment: Ohh nice! I will read the function mail right away. It was what i need. Thanks.

Comment: Question, i don't know how to set "$from_name" and "$email" into the header From: . Did you had a how to on this please?

Comment: @StéphaneRobert The "how to" is in the manual, as stated in my answer. There's no better way to learn than to read the manuals.

Comment: thanks. i had vote your answer. @fred -ii- did you know well php? i have another question i need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241784/php-form-mailfonction-and-google-recaptcha-validation-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code (not just the missing name attributes).

You have no `name` attributes for any of your inputs and error reporting would have thrown you something about it.

I.e.: For the `$_POST['courriel']` you would need to change your email input to: (you can't rely on an "id" alone).

```
<input type="email" name = "courriel" class="form-control" id="courriel" placeholder="Adresse courriel valide">
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and following that same pattern for all your other inputs.

However, and as I stated in comments. Your header will fail.

You're using 5 parameters. There is a 5th available, but isn't used for what you're doing.

```
mail($to, $courriel, $message, $headers,
 "From: $from\n" . 
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
        "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

The syntax is:

- To:
- Subject:
- Message:
- Headers

As per the manual on `mail()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

The 5th parameter is:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

Example of 5 parameters:

```
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,  '-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

An example from the manual on using the 4 parameters and sending as HTML:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I had another problem with reCaptcha validation once installed. 

I need to rebuild the PHP section to : 
If the captcha is Fail, the email is still sent.

I need to rebuild the code and don't know how.

Here the PHP code:

Comment: @StéphaneRobert Une question à la fois mon cher. Il faudrait que tu accèptes ma réponse afin de marquer ta question en étant résolue ;-)